# Symfony2 How to process dynamic embed forms collection?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I try this cookbook about embed form:
**http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html**

But the embed foreign key (task_id field in Tag table) is not save, always NULL

Here the complete code: **https://gist.github.com/1755140**

Do you know why?
Thank

**Edit:**:
My trouble was in process form action. Like the tag form is embed dynamically, so i don't know how many tag(s) i will have. If i add in createAction

```
$tag1 = new Tag();
$task->addTags($tag1);
```

only the first embed form was correctly save! How to save the other tags?

```
public function createAction(Request $request) 
{ 
    $task = new Task();
    $tag1 = new Tag();
    $task->addTags($tag1);

    $form    = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);        
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_task', array('id' => $task->getId())));   
    }

    return array(
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    ); 
}
```

**Edit2:**

My solution which resolve the trouble, what do you think about it? Better?

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{ 
        $task = new Task();
        $tasks = $request->request->get('task', array());
        if (isset($tasks['tags'])) {
            $tags = $tasks['tags'];
            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                $tag = new Tag();
                $task->addTags($tag);
            }
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);        
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($task);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_task', array('id' => $task->getId())));   
        }

        return array(
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        );
}
```

**Edit3:**

A much better alternative (not tested again)
http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-523899-creer-des-formulaires-avec-symfony2.html#ss_part_2

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{ 
    $task = new Task();
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);        
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        foreach($task->getTags() as $tag) {
            $em->persist($tag);
        }
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_task', array('id' => $task->getId())));   
    }

    return array(
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TaskController` on line 29 try to use `$task->addTags($tag1);` instead of `$task->getTags()->add($tag1);`

Comment: Not ok (but more readable) On the other side, if i add $tag1 = new Tag(); $task->addTags($tag1); in createAction, the first embed form was correctly save but not the others!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Is this solution wrong?

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    foreach($task->getTags() as $tag) {
        $tag->setTask($task);
    }
    $em->persist($task);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('new_task', array('id' => $task->getId())));   
}
```

It works and it seems simpler.

Comment: Sorry, i don't remember the solution, i switch to Propel. Propel rocks!